# Discord.py mentioning mentioned user

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a "!welcome (mention member)" command, which will then send a predefined message, tagging the member I mentioned. I want it to look like this, if for example, I typed "!welcome @Elastic_Disaster" --> https://gyazo.com/8e055cd380f0dd1e608c77f590ce631c

This is the code I've tried, but it does nothing.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def welcome (ctx, user = discord.Member):
    member = str(ctx.member)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} welcome to the server (and more welcome stuff here).')
```

Comment: You should read the documentation, its very good and covers everything. You are looking for `member.mention`

Comment: Believe me, I've tried the documentation to no avail. What would I need to add to my code/change to make it work? Thanks

Comment: Change `{member}` to `{member.mention}` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify a argument's class, you have to use `:` instead of `=`. Then, you can use [`discord.Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention) to mention the member.

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def welcome (ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} welcome to the server (and more welcome stuff here).')
```